# Where is the Magento grand total calculation code is located

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2

I need to make some changes in the grand total calculation in magento 2. I there is anybody who Knows the directory where code is located can Help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is available in

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php